# Rで一般化モーメント法(GMM)

Tags: r

Rで一般化モーメント法を行おうとしています。

しかし、統計の知識が乏しく、ドキュメントを読んでも、いまいち分かりません。

[image: RでのGMMの使用方法]

私は[この論文](http://www.slrc.kyushu-u.ac.jp/japanese/discussion/SLRC_DPS-10-1.pdf)の6ページ、(3)と（4）と似たようなことをしようとしています。

Rで(3)と(4)式の推定を行うためにはどのようなスクリプトを書けば良いのでしょうか？
合わせてどのようなデータセットを用意すればいいのかも教えていただけると幸いです。

正直な所、Usageにある変数が多く、統計の知識もないため、どの変数にどのデータを入れるべきか、全く見当がつきません。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: packageはgmm
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmm/gmm.pdf
でよろしいですか？

Comment: @user87562 さん。はい、gmmパッケージを利用しようと思っています。リンクの挿入数に制限があり、画像の参照元のURLを入れられませんでした。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/53674

Answer (score 1):

考えられる対処法として（すでに実施済みでしたらすいません）
1,英語で資料検索する
「GMM R」などで検索するとデータセットを使って検索した例が出てきます。
例えば
https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v034i11
http://www.brodrigues.co/2013/11/07/gmm-with-rmd
http://www.slideshare.net/shotayasui/dynamic-panel-in-tokyo-r
（最後のはRはあまり関係なく日本語資料ですが。）

また、`gmm`だけでなく`plm`や`systemfit`などのパッケージもGMMを計算できる模様です。

2,Stataなど他のソフトを使う
GMMなどの計量経済的な手法はStataやEviewsなどの方が得意なイメージがあるので使える環境にあったらそちらも頼ってみてはいかがでしょうか。それだと和書で今回の手法が探せる可能性もあります。

**追記**
論文6pに
「本稿でも Arellano and Bond(1991)の手法に基づくGMM推定によってパラメータの導出を行うものとする。」　
とあるので「Arellano Bond GMM」で検索すると当たりが出てきそうな感じでした。例えば[こちら](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111643/fit-measures-for-gmm-arellano-bond-estimator-in-r)とかです。日本語のページもそれなりに多かったです。
この記事の他にも`gmm`パッケージではなくパネルデータ処理用の`plm`パッケージの`pgmm`を使っているパターンが多いようです。（そもそもArellano Bond法はDynamicなPanel dataの処理法なので。）そちらのほうが参考ページも多そうなのでpgmmでトライした方がいいような気がします。

専門家ではないのでこの辺で一旦失礼させていただきます。

Comment: さん。ありがとうございました。理論的な解説やRのスクリプトの書き方の実例などがあり、とても参考になりました。pgmmも見てみます！

Comment: 解決したら後々同じ問題で悩む人のためにも追記をお願いします。
参考ページとかんたんな流れやコードだけでも十分なので。